# Using Spring Boot Configuration in a custom JUnit test runner that does not otherwise use Spring

Tags: spring, junit, configuration, spring-boot

I have a custom JUnit test runner that executes acceptance-level tests using a test specification format specific to my project.  The system under test is using Spring Boot and takes advantage of its configuration facility.  I'd like the tests to be able to read the same configuration files in the same way.  Obviously, using Spring Boot Configuration itself is an answer.

I'd like to just use Spring Boot Configuration as a stand-alone library, but I'm willing to fire up Spring Boot if that's what it takes.  I'm not in control of the top-level application - JUnit is.  So, I don't know how to start Spring Boot when I get control inside my test runner.

I've looked at extending SpringJunit4ClassRunner but I can't keep it from looking for @Test annotations and failing when it doesn't find any.  I've started to look into merging code from SpringJunit4ClassRunner into my custom runner.  Before I go too far down that path, I'd appreciate input from the community.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want the application running for a standalone webservice testing.  This can be done simply by scripting the "java -jar" command to run the spring boot application.  However,  I would question why you don't want to leverage the testing tools built into spring boot?  You can fire up the entire spring boot application and write some very logical looking tests.

For example a rest api test case:

```
@Test
public void homePage() throwsException () {
     mockMvc.perform(get("/readingList"))
         .andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(view().name("readingList"))
         .andExpect((model().attribute("books", is(empty()))));
}
```